# Сложносочиненные предложения. Запятая перед союзом и

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение

> Красная метка означает, что с документом что-то не так (запятая?) и им надо заняться (что включает в себя и вероятную переделку с нуля).

Объясните, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в этом случае? В интернете пишут, что запятая перед "и" нужна, в том числе, в случае сложносочиненного предложения: *Выпал снег, и лужи покрылись льдом*. Но я не понимаю, относится ли моё к ним.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При обобщающих словах *означает, что* перечисление не требует запятой. Что касается «переделки документа с нуля»... Есть предложение изменить эту часть фразы.

*Красная метка означает, что с документом что-то не так и им надо заняться; при этом допускается его полная правка.*